# Searching for a phrase

Tags: c#, .net, search, data-structures, tree

I've got an array of words, which are taken from a sentence (each word in the sentence is placed in an array).

A user can search for a phrase to see if it's found in this sentence. This is to be determined through the characters' offset values. This means that each word is checked to see if it exists in the phrase, separately, then a check is carried out to see if the words come after each other or not (separated by a space in the sentence).

The words are stored in a tree, and thus the offset values (character position) is the only thing which determines which word comes after which (and is separated by a space).

My problem is that words which are the same (and already stored in the tree) have the same offset values, and thus each word stores a data structure of all offset valuesattributed with the specific word. This is the code I've got so far, which works perfectly except that it fails in the following case:

For example I've got this sentence: `this is a test to see if this is working`.

If I search for 'this is a', then the first `this is` is returned as well as `this is a`.

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count - 1; i++)
{
    LinkedList<int> current = allOffsets[i];
    LinkedList<int> next = allOffsets[i + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < current.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < next.Count; k++)
        {
            if (current.ElementAt(j) + words[i].Length - 1 + 2 == next.ElementAt(k))
            {
                if (!finalResult.Contains(current.ElementAt(j)))
                {
                    finalResult.Add(current.ElementAt(j));
                }

                if (!finalResult.Contains(next.ElementAt(k)))
                {
                    finalResult.Add(next.ElementAt(k));
                }
            }
        }
     }
}

return finalResult;
```

Please note that `finalResult` is a list which stores all the 'valid' offsets, and `offsets` stores all the offsets in the tree. `words` is an array which contains all the words after they're split from the sentence.

**EDIT:** Also please note that I'm checking to see if the words follow each other by adding the offset of the first letter of a word by 2 (to account for the space) and this will be equal to the offset of the first letter of the next word, if it follows.

Comment: Is the desired output simply a string phrase?  Or do you need to use these offsets in the array for something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var source = new List<string>() { "this", "is", "a", "test", "to", "see", "if", "this", "is", "working" };
        var userInput = "this is a";
        var inputList = userInput.Split(' ');
        var inputListCount = inputList.Count();
        var exists = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inputList[0] == source[i])
            {
                var found = true;
                for (int j = 1; j < inputListCount; j++)
                {
                    if (inputList[j] != source[j])
                    {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found)
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(exists);
```

Comment: not sure what you want, but if you only want to check if it exists, I think my program can work.

Comment: While this looks good, it's not good for my problem unfortunately. Thanks anyway.